# Merge Pandas dataframe after multiple match

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 dataframes where I found common matches based on a column (`tld`), if a match is found (between a column in `source` and `destination`) I copied the value of column (`uuid`) from source to the `destination` dataframe.
I also check if a different column is a match. (`company_name`) then extract `uuid`.

Now I need to compare a different column (`similar_companies`) and extract `uuid` as well.

**Dataframe 1: source**

```
   uuid           website company_name           tld
0     1a  www.facebook.com     facebook  facebook.com
1     2b     www.yahoo.com    yahoo inc     yahoo.com
2     3c    www.google.com       Google    google.com
3     4d     www.cisco.com        Cisco     cisco.com
```

**Dataframe 2: destination**

```
  id           website  company_name           tld  match uuid
0  a  www.facebook.com      facebook  facebook.com  False  NaN
1  b         www.y.com     Yahoo Inc         y.com  False  NaN
2  c         www.g.com        Google         g.com  False  NaN
3  d         www.g.com    Google Inc         g.com  False  NaN
4  e  www.facebook.com  Facebook Inc  facebook.com  False  NaN
```

Desired output:

```
id           website  company_name           tld  match similar_companies
0  a  www.facebook.com      facebook  facebook.com   True          Facebook   
1  b         www.y.com     Yahoo Inc         y.com  False              None   
2  c         www.g.com        Google         g.com   True              None   
3  d         www.g.com    Google Inc         g.com  False              None   
4  e  www.facebook.com      Facebook  facebook.com   True          facebook   
5  f       www.face.uk  Facebook Inc       face.uk   True          facebook   

  uuid  
0   1a  
1  NaN  
2   3c  
3  NaN  
4   1a  
5   1a
```

Current code:

```
# Find if TLD is the same.
match_tld = destination.tld.isin(source.tld)
# Find if Company name is the same.
match_company_name = destination.company_name.isin(
      source.company_name)
# Find similar source.
destination[
      _SIMILAR_COMPANIES] = destination.company_name.apply(
          _FindSimilarCompanies, args=(destination,))
# Find if Company name is the same from similar source.
match_similar_companies = destination.similar_companies.isin(
      source.company_name)
# Update match column if TLD or company_name matches.
destination['match'] = match_tld | match_company_name | match_similar_companies
# Extract UUID for TLD matches.
merge_tld = destination.merge(
      source[['tld', 'uuid']], on='tld', how='left')
# Extract UUID for company name matches.
destination = destination.merge(
      source[['company_name', 'uuid']], on='company_name', how='left')
# I insert new line here!!!
# Combine dataframes.
destination['uuid'] = destination['uuid'].combine_first(merge_tld['uuid'])
logging.info(source)
logging.info(destination)
```

Above code works for 2 columns, but when I tried to merge the new column i get a KeyError: (I added a comment above where I insert the new code)

```
destination = destination.merge(
      source[['company_name', 'uuid']], on='similar_companies', how='left')
```

Error:

```
KeyError: 'similar_companies'
```

Comment: Sorry, `_SIMILAR_COMPANIES` is `similar_companies` ?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think problem is no column `similar_companies` in `source`, so is necessary `rename`:

```
#for sample data column
_SIMILAR_COMPANIES = 'similar_companies'
destination[_SIMILAR_COMPANIES] = destination.company_name.str.extract('([fF]acebook)')
```

---

```
destination1 = destination.merge(
      source[['company_name', 'uuid']], on='company_name', how='left')

destination2 = (destination.merge(
       source[['company_name', 'uuid']].rename(columns={'company_name':'similar_companies'}),
       on='similar_companies', how='left'))
# Combine dataframes.
merge_tld['uuid'] = (merge_tld['uuid'].combine_first(destination1['uuid'])
                                      .combine_first(destination2['uuid']))
print (merge_tld)
  id           website  company_name           tld  match similar_companies  \
0  a  www.facebook.com      facebook  facebook.com   True          facebook   
1  b         www.y.com     Yahoo Inc         y.com  False               NaN   
2  c         www.g.com        Google         g.com   True               NaN   
3  d         www.g.com    Google Inc         g.com  False               NaN   
4  e  www.facebook.com  Facebook Inc  facebook.com   True          Facebook   

  uuid  
0   1a  
1  NaN  
2   3c  
3  NaN  
4   1a
```